# A detail on Fubini's theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $f(x, y)$ be a measurable function on a product of two balls $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ respectively and $m,n\geq1$. We know, according to Fubini's theorem, that if $f$ is non-negative, then the iterated integrals 
$$\int_{B_{1}}\int_{B_{2}}f(x,y)dxdy$$
 and 
$$\int_{B_{2}}\int_{B_{1}}f(x,y)dydx$$
are equal in the sense that they both may be $+\infty$. My question is: Suppose that $f$ is not necessarily non-negative. If the iterated integrals are both finite, can they be different?
Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia's article on Fubini's theorem is a good one, there is an example ($m=n=1$) which you need, that is, it shows that even if both iterated integrals are finite then they might be different https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions and here are the conditions which you need for the integrals to be the same https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#The_Fubini.E2.80.93Tonelli_theorem